# Android - Twitter - Get the next 20 feeds and the next 20 and the next 20

Tags: android, twitter, feed

I dont't know what way is the better for to do it:

I have implement in my app one reader of twitter. I use this url:

http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?user_id=26707287

This url give me 20 last feeds; good but now I need implement a footer button in my list for load the next 20 feeds. I don't know what is the properly format of the url for to do this action.

Thank you !

Answer (score 2):

Check Twitter API documentation :)
http://dev.twitter.com/doc/get/statuses/user_timeline

You probably are interested in `count` and `page` parameters.
I think you have to use
http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?user_id=26707287&count=20&page=1
for the first page,

http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?user_id=26707287&count=20&page=2
for the second page

and so on